# I'm trying to copy text from a PDF, but I get garbage

Tags: ubuntu, pdf, encoding

I'm trying to copy text [from a PDF file](http://recursos.aldabaknocking.com/libpcapHakin9LuisMartinGarcia.pdf), but I get garbage. I'm using Document Reader on Ubuntu to read the document. It's not like its not allowing me to copy, but just that the copied text looks like this:

```
RFRPSLOHJFFDUSVQLIIHUFRDUSVQLIIOSFDS    

5XQDVURRW

LQFOXGHSFDSK!
LQFOXGHVWGOLEK!
LQFOXGHVWULQJK!

$53+HDGHUDVVXPLQJ(WKHUQHW,3Y

GH¿QH$53B5(48(67
$535HTXHVW

GH¿QH$53B5(3/<
$535HSO\

W\SHGHIVWUXFWDUSKGU^
XBLQWBWKW\SH
+DUGZDUH7\SH

XBLQWBWSW\SH
3URWRFRO7\SH

XBFKDUKOHQ
+DUGZDUH$GGUHVV/HQJWK

XBFKDUSOHQ
3URWRFRO$GGUHVV/HQJWK

XBLQWBWRSHU
2SHUDWLRQ&RGH

XBFKDUVKD>@
6HQGHUKDUGZDUHDGGUHVV

XBFKDUVSD>@
6HQGHU,3DGGUHVV

XBFKDUWKD>@
7DUJHWKDUGZDUHDGGUHVV

XBFKDUWSD>@
7DUJHW,3DGGUHVV
```

What can I do to fix this? its a large amount of data will take a really long time to type.

Also, incidentally, the pasted text looked like this on gedit (Ubuntu):

[image: on my system]
(notice that it looks different when pasted here in this question!)

I sense it is somehow an encoding problem, but I have no way of knowing how to fix this.

Comment: I think it's on purpose; the person who created the document purposefully made it so you couldn't copy/paste or export. I've had a few PDF's like this too. Mostly tables or excel spreadsheets made into PDFs by Adobe software.

Comment: @slhck sure! [here](http://recursos.aldabaknocking.com/libpcapHakin9LuisMartinGarcia.pdf) it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying text is garbled. I think @skub is correct to think that it may be on purpose. One way to get the text would be to export each page as an image (e.g. **.jpg** or **.png**) and then scan the images with [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) software. I was able to test this on Windows 7 with Adobe Acrobat X; it worked.

### Update:

If your document viewer has a similar feature, `copy with formatting` copies the text as expected. Digging deeper, I can confirm that the embedded fonts *all* have a **custom encoding**.

Comment: Here's more on [OCR stuff for Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OCR) (as the OP is using it).