# Why is copied text turned into garbage?

Tags: pdf

This is not the first PDF I get where some text can be successfully copied into the clipboard and pasted elsewhere, while other parts turn into garbage.

Here's an example:

[image]

I opened the same document with Adobe Acrobat, Foxit Reader, and SumatraPDF, and they all show the same issue.

Why does it  happen? Are some pages handled differently by the original PDF producer application (here : "PDFCreator")? Could it be that different pages of the original document were built with different tools (eg. Word for some pages, PowerPoint for others)?

Is there something I can try?

FWIW, this is on a Windows 7 host.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm trying to copy text from a PDF, but I get garbage](https://superuser.com/questions/383500/im-trying-to-copy-text-from-a-pdf-but-i-get-garbage)

Comment: Probably, but that other thread doesn't even come close to explaining _why_ it's garbled. There was a good Stack Overflow post by [Kurt Pfeifle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/359307/kurt-pfeifle) about font encoding tables in PDF documents (basically the document has the font glyph 'a' mapped to some _random byte_ instead of the actual ASCII 'a' 0x61), but unfortunately I can't find it anymore.

Comment: So I would honestly prefer to leave this open in case someone can post a decent explanation.

Comment: Are you asking the "technical" why? If so, then you would have to provide the PDF itself for review. There could be different ways the unicode mapping is incorrect. "Is there something I can try?" are you asking how to repair?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the PDF the character shapes may or may not be text (they could be vector paths). For example unlike Web Colour emoji fonts they may be monochrome shapes, that some writer fonts store as boxes (with or without image overlay) and others as monochrome symbolic equivalents in a font.

Primarily a character is say 10101010 and that is then mapped (CMap) to say Ascii A or emoji þ, in a named or nameless (CID) font. Especially if the font is not imbedded or sub-set, the chances are that character is different in a different users device ! So much for the original reason for PDF (trans-Portable Doc with Fonts).

If the character shift is simplistic, like Roman Cyphers, its possible to apply correction within the PDF reader, but in severe MojiBake cases the extraction is not mappable, nor correctable.

Usually the worst culprits can be OCR, where human intervention e.g. checking, was not part of the QA.